# Yii Session: Adding more info in "yiisession"

Tags: php, session, yii

Is there any possibility in Yii to add more info in "yiisession" table.

Be default the table has only "id", "expire" and "data" columns, I want to add another for a "userid" for my own use.

The reason to add the column so that my super user  can forcefully logout any user. Since the "id" written in Yii session is encrypted.

Any idea how to do that ?

(If it is not possible will it be ok to parse the "data" column to get desired session value ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own session storage class that can do the things you need by extending `CDbHttpSession` and adding the methods and properties you need. For example adding a id column could look like this:

```
class MyDbHttpSession extends CDbHttpSession
{
    public function setUserId($userId)
    {
        $db=$this->getDbConnection();
        $db->setActive(true);
        $db->createCommand()->update(
            $this->sessionTableName,
            array('userId'=>$userId), // I asume you added a column 'userId' to your session table
            'id=:id',
            array(':id'=>session_id())
       );
    }
}
```

Place your class in your application components directory and add it to your application config by setting the session component class to your new implementation:

```
// ...
'components' => array(
    // ...
    'session' => array(
        'class' => 'application.components.MyDbHttpSession',
        // ...
    )
    // ...
)
```